# How to phpunit this?

Tags: php, phpunit

```
class someTest {
  function setUp() {
    $this->dependency = $this->getMock('DependencyInterface');
    $this->testing = new classUnderTesting($dependency);
  }

  function test() {
    $objects = someFixture::Sample();
    $this->dependency->expects($this->at(0))
      ->method('something')
      ->with($objects);
    $this->testing->someMethod();
  }
}

class classUnderTesting {
  // Constructor stores the dependency.
  function someMethod() {
    // Same data but not an identical object.
    $objects = SomeOtherSource::returningTheSameAsSample();
    $this->dependency->something($objects);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
      $object->mutate();
    }
    return $objects;
  }
}
```

This fails phpunit because the `ObjectComparator` is called twice: once when `$this->dependency->something` is called with `$objects` which passes just fine but second time after the testing method finishes and `__phpunit_verify` fires and now `$objects`  have mutated. And they are stored in phpunit as well and because the way PHP5 works, they are the same objects so they have mutated so now they don't match. How can I unit test this? I found `enableArgumentCloning` and added it to `$this->dependency` but it didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same issue was filed https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1394 which is now closed in favor of https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/181 .

For now, I have simply applied the same `mutate` to the `$objects` in `someTest::test` at the very end of the test method. It seems nothing else exists ATM.